# How can I run function after each fold in cross_val_score() from scikit-learn?

Tags: callback, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to do cross-validation of my Keras neural networks with scikit-learn's `cross_val_score()` function.

The problem is that after each fold not only result is remembered, but also entire Keras model. So I would like to clear this model using `K.clear_session()` after each fold. But this are just details for context.

My main question is: **How can I run custom function after each fold with cross_val_score() from scikit-learn?** In other words: It is possible to run callback which should be run after each fold? Or there exists other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a custom callback and re write the on_train_end(self,logs={}) method of this callback. This new method will do stuff at the end of each training step. Something like that :

```
class CustomCall(Callback):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomCall, self).__init__()

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        # Stuff here
        print('\n Delete previous trained model : ')
        K.clear_session()
        return
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is, that K.clear_session() must be called after evaluation of model, not after training inside of cross_val_score(). So I must call K.clear_session() on end of cross val fold, not on end of Keras training.